# Write list-of-list to text file with writelines, space-separated?

Tags: python, output-formatting

I want to write a list-of-list to text file with `writelines()`, and using space as separators. Is there an easier way to do it than the following code?

```
myList = [[1, 'A1', 100, '1001', '1', '1001', 'aa'],
          [2, 'B1', 101, '3008', '2', '3008', 'bb'],
          [3, 'C1', 102, '6987414', '3', '6987414', 'cc']]
strList = []
for row in myList:
    myList = [str(item) for item in row]
    strList.append(myList)

with open(r"D:/20181210", "w",encoding="utf-8") as fo:
    for row in strList:
        list1 = [(item+" ") for item in row  ]
        fo.writelines( list1)
        fo.write('\n')
```

Then my text file output looks like this:

```
1 A1 100 1001 1 1001 aa 
2 B1 101 3008 2 3008 bb 
3 C1 102 6987414 3 6987414 cc
```

The result is right, but I think my code is not the easiest.

Comment: You could use `csv.Writer()` and specify space as the field delimiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or use `write` and use nested `str.join`:

```
with open(r"D:/20181210", "w",encoding="utf-8") as fo:
    fo.write('\n'.join([' '.join(i) for i in myList]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use the stdlib `csv` module as Barmar recommends, or build your strings with `str.join` and a genexp.

```
lines = [['some', 'space', 'separated', 'fields'],
         ['in', 'a', 'few', 'rows']]

with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(' '.join(line) for line in lines)
```

Comment: I used your code,but the result in txt just has one line likes this:`1 A1 100 1001 1 1001 aa2 B1 101 3008 2 3008 bb3 C1 102 6987414 3 6987414 cc`